# Can't see hidden objects-possibly glitching mesh?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh

I have tried moving all unncesarcy objects into a new collection so that it is only the iPhone mesh and cameras/etc. For some reason this is what I see in my viewport:
[image]

But this is what I see in the render:
[image]
I'm assuming its some hidden mesh but I don't see it...
I've attatched the blend. file:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your subdivision is acting with the mesh, because you have Ngons that's what is making that look. just delete that it's all good

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ah didn't see it was disabled in viewport, thank you!